# Instances won't align with normals

Tags: transforms, normals, geometry-nodes, properties, instances

So I've been experimenting with trying to align these instances with the normals of another object, and I can't get more than one to rotate. This also included rotating with anything else, like a random value or something, I cant get more than one to rotate.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Using blender 3.1.0

[.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U-8LzmfnocgsKqB8fQUKC4YqKOvVBW3B/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Nodes]

[image: Viewport]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing, that you want to align the local z-axis of the toruses to the normals, the following steps lead to this solution:

[image: result 1]

[image: result 2]

[image]

Realize the instances of the top/bottom points:

[image: realize instances]

Switch the *Object Info* node of *Plane.001* to relative:

[image: object info Plane.001]

You will have to adjust the BezierCurve, to place the toruses on top of *Plane.001*. Currently most of them lay inside.

Comment: I want them aligned to the normals of the linked object (Plane.001)
Ideally, they would rest on its surface